# GoogleMailSettingsService giving Error 403 on everything

Tags: c#, .net, google-data-api, google-email-settings-api

I am trying to retrieve labels with `GoogleMailSettingsService` through C# code but I am getting a 403 Forbidden error. I am using a Admin username / password, the "Use provisioning API" option is checked, and we have a business account.

```
GoogleMailSettingsService service = new GoogleMailSettingsService(domain, app_name);
service.setUserCredentials(user_name, password);
AppsExtendedFeed labels = service.RetrieveLabels(user_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to post this as a comment instead of an answer.
From the documentation Google provided, it looks like when a 403 error is received, it is possible that the account you are using is not an administrator.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/help/articles/provisioningoauth

Would you try to run it with a super admin account instead and see if the problem still persisted?